# Can PHP and node.js be used together?

Tags: php, node.js

Can a web app use both node.js and php? I would like to use php for the login system

Thanks

Comment: Yes.  For example you could have an apache server running mod_php and then proxy requests for certain locations to node.

Answer (score 0):

You know the way a node dev server defaults to :3000 ...

You could have both running on the same machine, using the same long term storage (database) to co-ordinate login and session state data.

Your PHP / apache running normally on port 80 (or the other way around), and run node on a port of your choice... It's possible but also a convoluted arrangement that I'd consider carefully....

The time you think you'll save implementing authentication using PHP may be well be wasted in mucking about with integration.